# Unable to get bounding box of Geohash

Tags: python, gis, centroid, geohashing

I'm trying to get the bounding box (x,y coordinates) of geohashes using Python's geohash module.  I'm able to successfully read in the geohashes and get their centroid, but when I try to use the `geohash.bbox()` method, it fails.  Here's code:

```
#import modules
import Geohash
import csv




    dataArray = []
    
    with open('C:\Users\Desktop\data.csv') as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in readCSV:
            geoHash = row[0] # this is the geohash identifier
            trips = row[1]
            share_of_trips = row[2]
            time_ID = row[3]
            perc_trips = row[4]
            geoStr = str(geoHash)
            latLong = Geohash.decode_exactly(geoStr)
            # Get Bounding Box
            boundingBox = Geohash.bbox(geoStr)
            print boundingBox
```

I'm able to successfully print the lat long pairs, but unable to get the bounding box.  The documentation says:

The error I'm getting is:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'bbox'
```

When I use `geohash`, as opposed to `Geohash`, it says `geohash is not defined.`

I've read the documentation:

geohash.bbox(hashcode) Bounding box for a geohash hashcode. This method returns a dictionary with keys of "s", "e", "w" and "n" which means South, East, West and North respectively.

```
>>> geohash.bbox('ezs42')
{'s': 42.5830078125, 'e': -5.5810546875, 'w': -5.625, 'n': 42.626953125}
```

Comment: Which geohashing library are you using? My google search came up with at least two different ones.

Comment: Please see my revised question - I have read the documentation.

Comment: I think you are confusing two different geohashing libraries. You need to find the library that has the features that you require.

Answer (score 1):

> but when I try to use the `geohash.bbox()` method, it fails

Your code has `Geohash.bbox()` which is not the same thing.

> When I use `geohash`, as opposed to `Geohash`, it says `geohash is not defined`.

That is because you have `import Geohash`. Maybe you need to change this to `import geohash` instead.

My google search for "python geohash" turns up at least two libraries. The documentation for one shows that you need to do `import Geohash`, but this library does not appear to have a `bbox()` function. The documentation for the second library has a `bbox()` function, but requires `import geohash`. I suggest you figure out which library you are using and look closely at the documentation **for that library** in order to determine correct usage.

Comment: it may be python-geohash, which I'm unable to use in Python 2.7 (i'm running PyCharm).  Frustrating .

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 "it may be" doesn't sound very definitive. You need to determine which library with much more certainty than that in order to use the correct documentation. Is there a good reason that you are using python 2.7? I strongly suggest that you use Python 3.x.

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 If you are in fact using python-geohash, then you need to do `import geohash` instead of `import Geohash`. Then `geohash.bbox()` will work.

Comment: No, I'm saying I'm unable to install python-geohash. I posted a question about this here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56367339/unable-to-get-bounding-box-of-geohash?noredirect=1#comment99339196_56367339

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 So we are back to my original question: Which library are you using that causes the error that you are asking about here?

Answer (score 1):

Try https://github.com/bashhike/libgeohash instead. Looks even better than the libraries you mentioned.

Here are some examples:

```py
import libgeohash as gh

shapleypolygon = gh.geohash_to_polygon(["u1q"])
bounds = shapleypolygon.bounds
print(bounds)
```

Outputs:

```py
(8.4375, 52.03125, 9.84375, 53.4375)
```

Or

```py
import libgeohash as gh
bbox = gh.bbox("u1q")
print(bbox)
```

Outputs:

```py
{'n': 53.4375, 's': 52.03125, 'w': 8.4375, 'e': 9.84375}
```

I find it very useful to convert the geohash to a shapely polygon using the `geohash_to_polygon` method.